# Is "there are two cars available for selection" correct?

Tags: conjunctions, adjective-phrases

Is the following sentence correct?

> There are two cars available for selection

If yes, why can the clause "available for selection" put behind the clause "There are two cars" without any conjunction? I don't quite understand; although it sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sentence is correct. Try to think about what is missing in that case? Why do you feel that the sentence is incomplete?

Likely, this will feel more complete to you:

> There are two cars **that are** available for selection.

"That are" is a relative clause, and so can be omitted in this case. You can more read about [relative clauses here.](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm)